# Trying to open an attachment in Slack: `{"ok":false,"error":"team_not_found"}` when clicking on "see it in full"

Tags: slack, attachment, json

I am trying to open an attachment (JSON file, a few KBs) in Slack that someone sent me and get the error:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"team_not_found"}
```

when clicking on "see it in full" after "This snippet was truncated for display".

What could be the issue?

---

Screenshots from Slack (used via the Slack website, not the desktop program or phone app)

[image]

[image]

Get blank page with `{"ok":false,"error":"team_not_found"}`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the other download button: interestingly, this one works:

[image]